# Use @Query to update table in Spring

Tags: java, spring, repository-pattern

I am trying to update a table using a custom Query in Spring but I get a **404 NOT FOUND** error

Here is my **repository** query

```
@Modifying
@Query("update AssignedFault af set af.userAssigned= :email where af.id= :id")
void allocateFault(@Param("email") String email, @Param("id") Long id);
```

Here is my **controller** method

```
@PutMapping("/assigned_faults/assign/{email}/{id}")
void assignFault(@PathVariable String email, @PathVariable Long id){
assignedFaultRepository.allocateFault(email, id);
}
```

Comment: which url are you invoking from your client layer?Can you paste the url.

Comment: I feel so stupid, it was the url.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On top of fixing the method code like this...

```
  @PutMapping("/assigned_faults/assign")
  void assignFault(@RequestParam String email, @RequestParam Long id){
  assignedFaultRepository.allocateFault(email, id);  
}
```

... I also added the **@Transactional** annotation to my repository interface